# Pass parameters as an object Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In python there is a convenient way of passing a dict to a function instead of variables, like here

```py
user = {
    'firstname':'John',
    'lastname': 'Wick'
}

def fullname(firstname, lastname):
    return firstname + ' ' + lastname

fullname(**user)
>>> 'John Wick'
```

instead of

```py
fullname(user['firstname'], user['lastname'])
>>> 'John Wick'
```

**Q**: Is there a similar way of passing an object to a function instead of variables in javascript?

**upd**: function is unchangeable

---

I tried using the `...` on the object, but it causes an error

```js
user = {
    'firstname':'John',
    'lastname': 'Wick'
}

function fullname(firstname, lastname){
    return firstname + ' ' + lastname;
}

fullname(...user)
>>> Uncaught TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
```

Comment: I don't think there is a complete equivalent, though, as in Python one can pass `user = { 'lastname': 'Wick', 'firstname':'John', }` and it would help you reorder things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not at the pc, so this could be wrong by try this:

```
fullname(...Object.values(user))
```

Comment: For this you possibly want to check that object property order is guaranteed for your environment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: Try passing `user = { 'lastname': 'Wick', 'firstname':'John', }` and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in `user`, and then you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object parameter.

```js
const user = {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Wick'
};

function fullname({ firstname, lastname }){
  return `${firstname} ${lastname}`;
}

console.log(fullname(user));
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: yeah, it works, but in my case I am using a function from a library, so it's unchangeable. should have mentioned that